# Ruby: Case using object

Tags: ruby, object, case

Is there a way to implicitly call methods on the object of a case statement?
IE:

```
class Foo

  def bar
    1
  end

  def baz
    ...
  end

end
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this...

```
foo = Foo.new
case foo
when .bar==1 then "something"
when .bar==2 then "something else"
when .baz==3 then "another thing"
end
```

... where the "when" statements are evaluating the return of methods on the case object. Is some structure like this possible? I haven't been able to figure out the syntax if so...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FWIW, you don't need to pass an object to a case statement in 1.8.7 at all.

```
foo = Foo.new()
case
when foo.bar == this then that
when foo.baz == this then that
end
```

I was surprised as hegg.

http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/

Comment: I think this is the closest thing to what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: oh, neat! Didn't know that. Given that, you could combine it with instance_exec (see my answer) to get almost exactly what you outlined in the question.

Comment: Andrew, no sweat. Ian, true that.

Answer (score 9):

What `case .. when` does is it calls the method `===` on your `when` values, passing your `foo` object as the argument to the `===` method. So in this code:

```
case foo
when 1 then "something"
when 2 then "something else"
when 3 then "another thing"
end
```

It will try `1 === foo`, then `2 === foo`, then `3 === foo`, until one of them returns a truthy value.

One way of making `case .. when` more powerful is using Procs as the `when` values. I'm not sure about earlier versions of Ruby, but in 1.9, `proc === x` is equivalent to `proc.call(x)`. So you can write code like this:

```
case foo
when Proc.new { foo.bar == 1 } then "something"
when Proc.new { foo.bar == 2 } then "something else"
when Proc.new { foo.baz == 3 } then "another thing"
end
```

Note that we don't even have to pass `foo` into the Procs, since we already have access to it. I don't think this is a very good choice of control structure for this example, a simple chain of ifs would make more sense:

```
if foo.bar == 1
  "something"
elsif foo.bar == 2
  "something else"
elsif foo.baz == 3
  "another thing"
end
```

Comment: The `===` behavior for Proc is a 1.9 thing, there's no mention of it in the [1.8.7 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Proc.html) but there is in the [1.9 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html#M000550).

Comment: +1 for `if` suggestion. This doesn't look like a proper place for `case` to begin with, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this was a useful read. I was really torn between your answer and hellodally's -- your is more informative overall, but his is what I'll actually end up using. Given that it was basically a toss-up, I gave him the answer since his rep is about 25,000 less than yours :) Thanks for the thorough explanation though!

Answer (score 6):

For different scenario where you want to test truthy method value of an object

```
class Foo
  def approved?
    false
  end

  def pending?
    true
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
case foo
when :approved?.to_proc
  puts 'Green'
when :pending?.to_proc
  puts 'Amber'
else
  puts 'Grey'
end

# This will output:  "Amber"
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're wanting to change the default receiver. This is hacky, but you could do something like:

```
string = Foo.new.instance_eval do
  if bar==1 then "something"
  elsif bar==2 then "something else"
  elsif baz==3 then "another thing"
  end
end
```

That's a big, terrible code smell, though, if you're just doing it because you're lazy. If you're doing it because you're creating a DSL, that's something else.